# Regular expression to match a block of text up to the first double new line?

Tags: php, regex, textile

I'm making a simple Textile parser and am trying to write a regular expression for "blockquote" but am having difficulty matching multiple new lines. Example:

```
bq. first line of quote
second line of quote
third line of quote

not part of the quote
```

It will be replaced with blockquote tags via `preg_replace()` so basically it needs to match everything between `"bq."` and the first double new line it comes across. The best I can manage is to get the first line of the quote. Thanks

Comment: By "simple" do you mean you're supporting a very small subset of Textile markup?  If not, I suggest you reconsider using `preg_replace()`; you'll soon find that it makes the job *more* difficult, not less.  You'll probably be better off not using regexes at all.

Comment: Yes, it is just a small portion of the markup I'm supporting. Out of interest, how would you do it without using regexes? Would of thought you had to use them at some point (even if using a preg_match) to find out what markup is being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?s)bq\.((?!(\r?\n){2}).)*+
```

meaning:

```
(?s)           # enable dot-all option
b              # match the character 'b'
q              # match the character 'q'
\.             # match the character '.'
(              # start capture group 1
  (?!          #   start negative look ahead
    (          #     start capture group 2
      \r?      #       match the character '\r' and match it once or none at all
      \n       #       match the character '\n'
    ){2}       #     end capture group 2 and repeat it exactly 2 times
  )            #   end negative look ahead
  .            #   match any character
)*+            # end capture group 1 and repeat it zero or more times, possessively
```

The `\r?\n` matches a Windows, *nix and (newer) MacOS line breaks. If you need to account for real old Mac computers, add the single `\r` to it: `\r?\n|\r`

Comment: I would probably use `{2}` in place of `{2,}` because you can't tell if eating all adjacent newlines is desirable. It's certainly not part of the requirement.

Comment: +1, very nice. Why the possessive quantifier, though, if nothing else follows the capturing group?

Comment: @Tim: since the `.` matched by group 1 will never be one of the line breaks from `\n\n` (because of the negative look ahead), it is safe to possessively capture it. That way, the regex engine does not keep track of all states the`.` captures (no need for backtracking). With relative small strings it won't matter much, but when the strings get large, performance may very well increase by using the possessive quantifier.

Comment: @Bart, did you use your auto-explainer for that?  And have you gone public with it yet?

Comment: @Alan, yes, I used my auto-explainer tool for that. It's still (heavily) under development, but you can download a beta-ish version here: http://big-o.nl/apps/pcreparser/ Besides an ascii exlanation, it also builds a nice JTree from the regex.

Answer (score 1):

This accepted answer only captured the last character of the block for me.  I ended up using this:

```
$text =~ /(?s)bq\.(.+?)\n\n/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
'/(.+)\n\n/s'
```

I believe 's' stands for single line.

Comment: `s` is usually called 'dot-all' (since it will let the `.` match line breaks as well). But doing what you suggest will cause the regex to match all text, and will then backtrack in the string to find the last `\n\n`. From the string `ABC\n\nDEF\n\nGHIJ\n\nKLM`, it will match `ABC\n\nDEF\n\nGHIJ\n\n`. Not what the Fourjays is looking for IMO.

Comment: That's true. Would have to make + non-hungry I guess.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My instincts tell me something like...

```
preg_match("/^bq\. (.+?)\n\n/s", $input, $matches)
```

Just like the above fella says, the `s` flag after the `/` at the end of the RegEx means that the `.` will match new line characters. Usually, without this, RegExs are kind of a one line thing.

Then the question mark `?` after the `.+` denotes a non-greedy match so that the `.+` won't match as it can; instead it will match the minimum possible, so that the `\n\n` will match the first available double line.

To what extent are you planning on supporting features of Textile? Because your RegEx can get pretty complicated, as Textile allows things like...

```
bq.. This is a block quote

This is still a block quote
```

or...

```
bq(funky). This is a block quote belonging to the class funky!

bq{color:red;}. Block quote with red text!
```

All of which your regex-replace technique won't be able to handle, methinks.

Comment: I'm only supporting what I'd consider the "most common" features (bold, italic, strikethrough, quotes, titles, paragraphs, bullets). Would only use the classes on the paragraph at the very most. So far the regex's work well for things like bold, but I suspect I'm going to have to do something more involved for the bulleted list.

Comment: ... and nested bold/italics? I think that `*this is _not_ going to work with RegEx*`

Comment: Nested bold/italics seem to work fine. Using the regex's it does a straight replace of the contents of the bold "tag" so the italics are left untouched.

Comment: k, cool! Sorry to hassle you on the matter - I wrote my own Textile interpreter once for kicks and loved doing it, so I'm very interested.

Comment: No problem. I'm mostly doing it as an experiment too. Regex's are my nemesis though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ehr, misread the question.. "bq." was significant.

```
echo preg_replace('/^bq\.(.+?)\n\n/s', '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', $str, 1);
```

Sometimes data that is entered via webforms contains \r\n instead of just \n which would make it

```
echo preg_replace('/^bq\.(.+?)\r\n\r\n/s', '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', $str, 1);
```

The questionmark makes it add the closing blockquotes after the first double return found ("non-greedy" I believe it's called), so any other double returns are left alone (if that is not what you want, take it out obviously).