# Where did I go wrong in my regex lookaround?

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I'm trying to pull the first paragraph out of Markdown formatted documents:

> This is the first paragraph.
>
> This is the second paragraph.

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222209/regular-expression-to-match-a-block-of-text-up-to-the-first-double-new-line) gives me a solution that matches the first string ending in a double line break.

Perfect, except some of the texts begin with Markdown-style headers:

> `###` This is an h3 header.
>
> This is the first paragraph.

So I need to:

- Skip any line that begins with one or more `#` symbols.
- Match the first string ending in a double line break.

In other words, return 'This is the first paragraph' in both of the examples above.

So far, I've tried many variations on:

```
"/(?s)(?:(?!\#))((?!(\r?\n){2}).)*+/
```

But I can't get it to return the proper match.

Where did I go wrong in my lookaround?

I'm doing this in PHP (preg_match()), if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
"/(?sm)^[^#](?:(?!(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2}).)*/"
```

I enable the multiline option by using `(?sm)` instead of `(?s)` and start each check at a new line, which may not be starting with a #. And I used `\r\n|\r|\n` instead of `\r?\n` because my testing environment had funny line breaks =)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! (And now off to learn more about (?sm). =)