# How would I match a block of text containing max one newline in a row and preceded by two?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, newline

How would I match a block of text that contains max one new line? The block of text may not be in a tag. This is what I've currently got.

```
$pPattern = '
    /(?<=\n|\A) # Preceded by a new line or at the start of the file
    (?!<.*>(?:.|\n)*<\/.*>) # Not within a tag
    (.+) # Need help here
    (?=\n\n|\Z) # Succeeded by double newlines or at end of file
/muxi';
$text = preg_replace($pPattern, "<p>$1</p>", $text);
```

I've tried a few different capture groups without success such as `((?:.+\n?)+)`. Anyone got any suggestions?

I found this: [Regular expression to match a block of text up to the first double new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222209/regular-expression-to-match-a-block-of-text-up-to-the-first-double-new-line) while searching and tried using some of that code but couldn't get it to work.

Edit: As an example I'll use this block of text as an example

```
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
Nulla at erat velit, eu tristique massa.
Donec vehicula lorem et lacus ullamcorper id bibendum nisi euismod.
Vestibulum ac leo nisl, nec fermentum quam.

Maecenas velit ante, varius a interdum molestie, viverra et nunc. In elit erat, interdum in elementum eget, bibendum at augue. Praesent nec quam justo. Cras vestibulum accumsan vehicula. Curabitur leo velit, blandit eget consectetur id, commodo eu ipsum. Nulla vel lacus dolor, a suscipit purus. Aliquam euismod interdum elementum.

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>

Donec quis odio iaculis tellus suscipit porta. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut sed risus diam, at ultrices mi. Vestibulum vitae leo justo, eget ultricies diam. Curabitur pharetra ornare lorem, ac semper tortor fringilla ut. Etiam et nisl felis. Quisque ac purus ipsum. Donec interdum elit ac nunc rhoncus eu pulvinar massa ornare. Fusce turpis est, commodo lacinia vulputate at, hendrerit eget tortor.
```

From that I get the following output:

```
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
Nulla at erat velit, eu tristique massa.
Donec vehicula lorem et lacus ullamcorper id bibendum nisi euismod.
<p>Vestibulum ac leo nisl, nec fermentum quam.</p>

<p>Maecenas velit ante, varius a interdum molestie, viverra et nunc. In elit erat, interdum in elementum eget, bibendum at augue. Praesent nec quam justo. Cras vestibulum accumsan vehicula. Curabitur leo velit, blandit eget consectetur id, commodo eu ipsum. Nulla vel lacus dolor, a suscipit purus. Aliquam euismod interdum elementum.</p>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
<p></ul></p>

<p>Donec quis odio iaculis tellus suscipit porta. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut sed risus diam, at ultrices mi. Vestibulum vitae leo justo, eget ultricies diam. Curabitur pharetra ornare lorem, ac semper tortor fringilla ut. Etiam et nisl felis. Quisque ac purus ipsum. Donec interdum elit ac nunc rhoncus eu pulvinar massa ornare. Fusce turpis est, commodo lacinia vulputate at, hendrerit eget tortor.</p>
```

But I want this output:

```
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
<p>Nulla at erat velit, eu tristique massa.
Donec vehicula lorem et lacus ullamcorper id bibendum nisi euismod.
Vestibulum ac leo nisl, nec fermentum quam.</p>

<p>Maecenas velit ante, varius a interdum molestie, viverra et nunc. In elit erat, interdum in elementum eget, bibendum at augue. Praesent nec quam justo. Cras vestibulum accumsan vehicula. Curabitur leo velit, blandit eget consectetur id, commodo eu ipsum. Nulla vel lacus dolor, a suscipit purus. Aliquam euismod interdum elementum.</p>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>

<p>Donec quis odio iaculis tellus suscipit porta. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut sed risus diam, at ultrices mi. Vestibulum vitae leo justo, eget ultricies diam. Curabitur pharetra ornare lorem, ac semper tortor fringilla ut. Etiam et nisl felis. Quisque ac purus ipsum. Donec interdum elit ac nunc rhoncus eu pulvinar massa ornare. Fusce turpis est, commodo lacinia vulputate at, hendrerit eget tortor.</p>
```

Comment: Please clarify: What are you trying to match? Can you give a couple of examples? What isn't working with your current regex?

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur: I updated my question with an example. I hope that you understand what I mean now.

Comment: What about `one line\n<h1>a header</h1>\nanother line`? or `a line <a href="a.htm">with a link</a> in it`?

Comment: Except for this in-vs-out of tag thing, I would just read it in a paragraph at a time.

Comment: I know exactly which tags the string will contain and it will only contain ul, li and h2 tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace("/(\n\n|^)([^<].*)(\n\n|$)/U", '$1<p>$2</p>$3', $str);
```

It encloses in <p></p> all text parts between (\n\n OR start of string) AND (\n\n OR end of string) AND starts with any character except for "<" (which tells as that line starts with a tag).

Comment: I don't know if this is correct however I managed to figure it out somehow i just don't remember how. This is half a year old.

Comment: Oops. I've hunted for unanswered questions on regular expressions and didn't noticed the date.