# select a block of text seperated by double newlines in visual studio using regex

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to write a regex in visual studio which will capture any block of text separated by double newlines, so I can surround them with a Doxygen comment.

i.e.

```
namespace
{
   int a;
   int b;

   double c;
   double d;

   bool e;
   bool f;
}
```

to become:

```
namespace
{
   /** @{ */
   int a;
   int b;
   /** @} */

   /** @{ */
   double c;
   double d;
   /** @} */

   /** @{ */
   bool e;
   bool f;
   /** @} */
}
```

I've already tried the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222209/regular-expression-to-match-a-block-of-text-up-to-the-first-double-new-line), but even unmodified (which isn't exactly suitable), visual studio gives me an error that the

> 'The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.'

I've also tried:

```
(\r?\n){2}(.*\s)+(\r?\n){2}
```

which just hangs indefinitely, as I think the `(.*\s)` end up matching just about every permutation of everything in the entire file.

Comment: It does not hang for me. However, it only matches `double c; double d;`

Comment: @WiktorStribizew does it actually select blocks of text?

Comment: Yes, if you enable the regex mode (ALT + E when the find&replace pane is visible).

Comment: Try `((?:\r?\n){2}|^\s*)([\S\s]+?)((?:\r?\n){2})` -> `$1/** @{ */\r\n$2\r\n/** @} */$3`, but I thin you will have to adjust whitespace later.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew thanks, that regex is definitely very close to what I need.

Comment: Use `(^\s*namespace\b\s*\{|(?!^)\G)((?:\r?\n){2}([ \t]*)|(?:[ \t]*\r?\n)*([ \t]*))([\S\s]+?)(?=[ \t]*(?:\s+\}|(?:\r?\n){2}))` in Notepad++ to replace with `$1$2/** @{ */\r\n$3$4$5\r\n$3$4/** @} */` and remove the last empty `/** @{ */  /** @} */` with `/\*\* @\{ \*/\s*/\*\* @\} \*/` regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex that does what you need **in Notepad++**, together with the correct indentation:

```
(^\s*namespace\b\s*\{|(?!^)\G)((?:\r?\n){2}([ \t]*)|(?:[ \t]*\r?\n)*([ \t]*))(\S[\S\s]*?)(?=[ \t]*(?:\s+\}|(?:\r?\n){2}))
```

And replace with `$1$2/** @{ */\r\n$3$4$5\r\n$3$4/** @} */`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5E%5Cs*namespace%5Cb%5Cs*%5C%7B%7C(%3F!%5E)%5CG)((%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn)%7B2%7D(%5B%20%5Ct%5D*)%7C(%3F%3A%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%5Cr%3F%5Cn)*(%5B%20%5Ct%5D*))(%5CS%5B%5CS%5Cs%5D*%3F)(%3F%3D%5B%20%5Ct%5D*(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5C%7D%7C(%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn)%7B2%7D))&i=namespace%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20int%20a%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20int%20b%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20double%20c%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20double%20d%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20bool%20e%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20bool%20f%3B%0D%0A%7D&r=%241%242%2F**%20%40%7B%20*%2F%0D%0A%243%244%245%0D%0A%243%244%2F**%20%40%7D%20*%2F) and Notepad++ demo:

[image]

I believe the

*Find what*: `(?<=^\s*namespace\b\s*\{(?:(?!\r?\n[ \t]*}\r?\n)[\S\s])*)((?:\r?\n){2}([ \t]*)|(?:[ \t]*\r?\n)*([ \t]*))(\S[\S\s]*?)(?=[ \t]*(?:\s+\}|(?:\r?\n){2}))`
*Replace with*: `$1/** @{ */\r\n$2$3$4\r\n$2$3/** @} */`

Should [also work](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cs*namespace%5Cb%5Cs*%5C%7B(%3F%3A(%3F!%5Cr%3F%5Cn%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%7D%5Cr%3F%5Cn)%5B%5CS%5Cs%5D)*)((%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn)%7B2%7D(%5B%20%5Ct%5D*)%7C(%3F%3A%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%5Cr%3F%5Cn)*(%5B%20%5Ct%5D*))(%5CS%5B%5CS%5Cs%5D*%3F)(%3F%3D%5B%20%5Ct%5D*(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5C%7D%7C(%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn)%7B2%7D))&i=namespace%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20int%20a%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20int%20b%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20double%20c%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20double%20d%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20bool%20e%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20bool%20f%3B%0D%0A%7D&r=%241%2F**%20%40%7B%20*%2F%0D%0A%242%243%244%0D%0A%242%243%2F**%20%40%7D%20*%2F&o=m) in VS2015 S&R, but right now, the `$n` backreferences are not working at all with this regex, and I cannot find out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting from the opening bracket of the namespace to the closing bracket (inclusive of the brackets), the following regex's gave me the desired result, including white-space:

FIND:    `((?:\r?\n){2}|(\s*)\{?\s*)((\s+)\S[\S\s]+?)((?:\r?\n){2}|(?:\r?\n)\s*\})`

REPLACE: `$1$4/** @{ */\r\n$2$3\r\n$2$4/** @} */$5`