# php preg_replace_callback blockquote regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a REGEX that will

**`Input`**

```
> quote
the rest of it

> another paragraph
the rest of it
```

And **`OUTPUT`**

> quote
> the rest of it
>
> another paragraph
> the rest of it

with a resulting **`HTML`** of

```
<blockquote>
<p>quote
the rest of it</p>
<p>another paragraph
the rest of it</p>
</blockquote>
```

This is what I have below

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/^>(.*)(...)$/m',function($matches){
    return '<blockquote>'.$matches[1].'</blockquote>';
},$text);
```

[**`DEMO`**](http://parsedown.org/tests/lazy_blockquote)

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: if it's just the > char you are trying to remove, can you simple use /^>/m as the pattern and then replace this with "" (empty) ? Then after the preg_replace, just creating a string with <blockquote>'.$text.'</blockquote>

Comment: could you show me the code by editing the code?

Comment: `$text = preg_replace("/^>/m","<blockquote>aaa</blockquote>",$text);`  is this?

Comment: if you want to <p> tags included, use the answer below

Comment: Try [`$text = "<blockquote>\n".preg_replace('/^>\s*(.*?)\s*(?=^>|\Z)/ms', "<p>$1</p>\n", $text).'</blockquote>';`](https://eval.in/958062)

Comment: @RamazanŞAHİN Please improve your question by offering a couple more sample strings.  Is this your full input string?  Are they always entirely blockquote strings?  It is important that we know how your input may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for the given example.

```
$text = "> quote
the rest of it

> another paragraph
the rest of it";


preg_match_all('/^>([\w\s]+)/m', $text, $matches);

$out = $text ;
if (!empty($matches)) {
    $out = '<blockquote>';
    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
        $out .= '<p>'.trim($match).'</p>';
    }
    $out .= '</blockquote>';
}

echo $out ;
```

Outputs :

```
<blockquote><p>quote 
the rest of it</p><p>another paragraph
the rest of it</p></blockquote>
```

Comment: it is necessary to repeat the same until the end. to finish

Comment: I can not turn off the tag `>`

Comment: `$text = "> test1
test2
test3

no finish? problem";`

Comment: [code image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5828703/36345611-4b778426-143f-11e8-9e26-fbce02c32cf7.PNG) - [output image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5828703/36345615-7eacd40e-143f-11e8-8769-f39886cbc7be.PNG)

Comment: @RamazanŞAHİN I'm sorry. I cannot fix this :( I could delete my anwser if it doesn't helps you enough.

Comment: this is hard, but i will

Comment: @RamazanŞAHİN Thank you too !

Comment: it's that simple :)
 `'/^> ([\w\s]+)\s+\s+/m'`

Comment: @RamazanŞAHİN using `\s+\s+` is nonsense.

Comment: @mickmackusa can be better. this is a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?s)>((?!(\r?\n){2}).)*+
```

meaning:

```
(?s)           # enable dot-all option
b              # match the character 'b'
q              # match the character 'q'
\.             # match the character '.'
(              # start capture group 1
  (?!          #   start negative look ahead
    (          #     start capture group 2
      \r?      #       match the character '\r' and match it once or none at all
      \n       #       match the character '\n'
    ){2}       #     end capture group 2 and repeat it exactly 2 times
  )            #   end negative look ahead
  .            #   match any character
)*+            # end capture group 1 and repeat it zero or more times, possessively
```

The `\r?\n` matches a Windows, *nix and (newer) MacOS line breaks. If you need to account for real old Mac computers, add the single `\r` to it: `\r?\n|\r`

question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222331/9238511

Comment: @mickmackusa okay ?

Comment: I need more sample inputs from the OP.